# Remote ssh login causes local login to freeze?

Tags: ssh, centos7, login

I have a Cent OS 7 server running. I log into it from a local-network laptop using 'ssh -X', which works just fine. I go down to the server room and connect the rack monitor to the server, the welcome screen comes on after a little while, then I click the same user account. It asks for a password and seems to accept it. The screen now goes dark/blank and nothing happens. If I go back to the laptop, everything is still working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting a graphical login in the server room? The graphical login environment could be broken. You could try Control+Alt+F1 to bring up a text-based session similar to SSH. If you can log in to the console via text, then you can begin to investigate what went wrong with the graphical login.

Comment: Yes, the server room login is graphical.

Further adventures: We reboot the server, log into it (graphically and locally), launch VirtualBox and start running a long loop process in a VM.  I then go remote, log into the server (ssh -X), and open the VM's log using gedit (the log is generated inside the VM but written to a file on a folder shared with the VirtualBox host, so itcan be looked at without interfering with the VM).  It sees the loops go on for a while.  Eventually, something goes wrong with the server: the VM keeps logging a seemingly irrelevant error and (continued)

Comment: ...once I go back to the server's local screen, there is a grey message about "something has gone wrong, you must logout". Logging out kills VirtualBox.  But if we then try to log back in from the server's local screen, I get the black/blank screen again.  Meanwhile, the remote connection still works fine (which is how I found out VirtualBox was no longer running).  Apparently, all the while the server was displaying its error screen, the virtual machine kept logging the same error.

Comment: This is a manifestation of the so-called "fail whale" ("Oh No! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."), so I'm trying removing gnome-settings-daemon from the RequiredComponents of /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.session. We'll see how that goes. Also broadened access to /run/user/1001/dconf/user in order to get rid of the multitudinous 'dconf-CRITICAL' messages that pollute the logs.